# Whitespace & $null variable handling in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will grab all users in an OU and change the current primary alias to a secondary alias while adding a new primary smtp address and retaining any other secondary aliases. We have users with 0 aliases, some with 1, some with 2, and some with 3. I am running into an issue when any one of the $sp1, $sp2, $sp3, $sp4, $sp5 are either white space or null. I'm still learning powershell so I'm not sure how to handle that without a lot of pain lol.

```
$Users = Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestScriptedSMTPAddrChange,OU=***,DC=***,DC=com" -Properties proxyAddresses | Select-Object SamAccountName, proxyAddresses #Change first OU= to the OU you want to change


Foreach ($SAN in $Users){
    $SecondaryProxyRaw = $SAN.proxyAddresses #grab proxyAddresses and dump them
    $SecondaryProxyRed = $SecondaryProxyRaw.replace('SMTP','smtp') #change primary SMTP addr to secondary smtp addr
    $sp1,$sp2,$sp3,$sp4,$sp5 = $SecondaryProxyRed.split(" ",1) #split the proxyAddresses array into variables
    $NewPrimaryProxy = "SMTP:$($SAN.SamAccountName)@newdomain.com"} #assign new primary SMTP address
    Set-ADUser -Identity $SAN.SamAccountName -replace @{proxyAddresses = "$NewPrimaryProxy","$sp1","$sp2","$sp3","$sp4","$sp5"}
}

Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestScriptedSMTPAddrChange,OU=***,DC=***,DC=com" -Properties proxyAddresses | Select-Object SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, @{Name="Proxyaddresses";Expression={$_.proxyAddresses -join "*"}}
```

Comment: Try `-split $SecondaryProxyRed` instead of `$SecondaryProxyRed.split(" ")`

Comment: you can build a splat [hashtable of parameters & values] one parameter at a time. that way, you can test for "is it blank?" and only add the ones that have proper values added to the splat. take a look at `Get-Help about_Splatting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on a user having 1, 3 or perhaps 77 addresses in its `proxyAddresses` attribute by trying to split these into a fixed number of variables.

Just get them all, replace the uppercase `SMTP:` into lowercase 'smtp:', filter out the possible one that would be equal to the new proxy address and add the new primary address to the array.
Then, replace the entire proxyAddresses array with the **strongly typed** (i.e. cast to `string[]]`) new array.

```
$Users = Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestScriptedSMTPAddrChange,OU=***,DC=***,DC=com" -Properties proxyAddresses

foreach ($SAN in $Users) {
    $NewPrimaryProxy = 'SMTP:{0}@newdomain.com' -f $SAN.SamAccountName
    # if you like you can sort the proxies but for the system this will have no effect
    $proxies = @($SAN.ProxyAddresses -replace '^SMTP:', 'smtp:' | Where-Object { $_ -ne $NewPrimaryProxy }) + $NewPrimaryProxy
    # Note: proxyAddresses needs a Strongly typed string array, that is why we cast $proxies array with [string[]]
    $SAN | Set-ADUser -Replace @{proxyAddresses = [string[]]$proxies}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `.split(" ",1)`

doesn't split at all - by definition it returns the input string as-is, because you're asking for `1` token only - see the docs for the .NET `[string]` type's [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.split#system-string-split(system-char()-system-int32)) method.

To split by runs of whitespace, you can use the unary form of PowerShell's [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) *operator*:

```
# Split by whitespace and collect tokens in an array.
# -ne '' filters out empty elements, so that if 
# $SecondaryProxyRed is effectively empty, $sps becomes an empty array.
$sps = -split $SecondaryProxyRed -ne ''
```

You can then create an array with `$NewPrimaryProxy` as the first element, followed by the elements of `$sps`, if any:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $SAN.SamAccountName -replace @{
  proxyAddresses = @($NewPrimaryProxy) + $sps
}
```